# Regular expression pattern to match image url from text

Tags: regex

I'm using this regex but not match url with subdomain.

```
(https?://[^\s]+(?=\.(jpe?g|png|gif))).(jpe?g|png|gif)
```

Match: `http://domain.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/image.jpg`

Not match: `http://sub.domain.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/image.jpg`

Comment: matches both of them for me. http://rubular.com/r/OYpTYgvrH9

Comment: `^https?:\/\/[^\s]+(?=.(jpe?g|png|gif)).\1$`, a little concise

Answer (score 1):

This regex matches **well formed** URLs (including those with subdomains, port number and query string) of JPG, PNG and GIF images:

`((?:https?\:\/\/)(?:[a-zA-Z]{1}(?:[\w\-]+\.)+(?:[\w]{2,5}))(?:\:[\d]{1,5})?\/(?:[^\s\/]+\/)*(?:[^\s]+\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png))(?:\?\w+=\w+(?:&\w+=\w+)*)?)`

PHP example:

```
<?php

$str = 'Lorem ipsum http://example.com/img.jpg dolor sit http://www.aaa.cc/this/is/not/an/image.html amet, consectetur http://my.domain.com/path/to/nothing.gif adipiscing elit http://www.imgbucket.com/some/other/image.png';

preg_match_all('@((?:https?\:\/\/)(?:[a-zA-Z]{1}(?:[\w\-]+\.)+(?:[\w]{2,5}))(?:\:[\d]{1,5})?\/(?:[^\s\/]+\/)*(?:[^\s]+\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png))(?:\?\w+=\w+(?:&\w+=\w+)*)?)@', $str, $matches);

print_r($matches[1]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://example.com/img.jpg
    [1] => http://my.domain.com/path/to/nothing.gif
    [2] => http://www.imgbucket.com/some/other/image.png
)
```

Comment: It doesn't match this ((?:https?\:\/\/)(?:[a-zA-Z]{1}(?:[\w\-]+\.)+(?:[\w]{2,5}))(?:\:[\d]{1,5})?\/(?:[^\s\/]+\/)*(?:[^\s]+\.(?:png|jpe?g|gif|svg|PNG|JPE?G|GIF|SVG))(?:\?\w+=\w+(?:&\w+=\w+)*)?)

Answer (score -1):

```
https?://\w+\.\w+/\S+\.(jpe?g|png|gif)
```

will match only one dot before the first `/`.

`\S` is the same as `[^\s]`, only shorter.